# How to find usage of deprecated code in kotlin with intellij-idea

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, refactoring

I want to automatically find all occurrences in my kotlin application where i use deprecated code (mostly methods which are annotated as deprecated)

I'm talking not about kotlin code which is deprecated in the kotlin spec, i mean kotlin code which calls a deprecated function/method.

The source where the deprecated function is located could be kotlin- or java- libraries.

I found really great tooling for finding similar issues in java code via intellij idea, like:

- code -> inspect code
- code -> analyse code -> inspection by name -> deprecated API usage
- edit -> find -> find structurally -> select template deprecated methods (only available for java)

But i don't find a way for any similar search option for kotlin.

I tried to build a "deprecated api usage structural search"-template myself, but base functionalities to archive this seems not be supported for kotlin.

The only none manual function which works is the local code analyse of the file i'm currently in (this little hind in the upper right corner where you can see number of issues (and can click on them to have them in the a list))

This works but if i make a code analyse for a hole folder the deprecated usages are not there.

I need a solution for scanning the hole code base and not manually clicking from file to file.

Edit:
please note that there is now already a ticket created for jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311206

Because it seems like there is no solution or workaround currently in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now got an answer and a working solution from my (second) ticket at jetbrains for this topic (one ticket for inspect code analyse and one for structural search):
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24477

It turns out that the structural search template `Reference` attribute "Deprecated Method" i use on the `$MethodCall$` variable (the same way as it's for java in the existing template "Method calls to deprecate methods"), is not supported for kotlin templates.

In fact this `Reference` attribute works differently then i thought but it's also more generic and powerful. You could select any structural search template there as a "preprocessing" search which limits the input on your current template (at least that's for now my conceptual model of it)

This fit's to the solution i got from jetbrains, which means that i'm doing the following:

First make a new template for finding kotlin methods which flagged as deprecated:

```
@Deprecated($Parameters$) 
fun $MethodCall$($Parameter$)
```

Then saving this with a name like `deprecated kotlin methods`.

Then create a new Template for finding code which is calling such deprecated methods. The template looks like:

```
$MethodCall$.($Parameters$)
```

Where parameters are set to range between `0 - *`.
And now set the `Reference` attribute to the custom template which was wrote beforehand (in this example it's named `deprecated kotlin methods`.

Now these calls to deprecated kotlin methods are found!

If you want to find deprecated java code which is called by your kotlin code base (e.g. which are inside of libs) then you could do the same apporoach. But this time you create a custom template for the `Reference` attribute which is based on Java and uses the Java Deprecated annotation. Combining this inside a kotlin template seems to works.

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of manual work required for such an obviously helpful task!

Answer (score 0):

@Deprecated warning is a compiler warning, and you can not find it via IDE inspection search yet. Please follow an issue — https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-12494/Analyze-Inspect-code-Inspection-results-show-compiler-warnings

Comment: i guess we are talking about different things (maybe i have to be more clear on the question. I don't talk about kotlin code which is deprecated in the kotlin spec. I talk about kotlin code which uses a method (most times from an external library could be java or kotliin) which is marked as deprecated. I guess thats what is meant when you search for java analyse by name "deprecated API usage" (which is not available for kotlin). btw. i adjusted the question, to be more precise.

Comment: Thank you! Can you try `Kotlin | Migration | Usage of redundant or deprecated syntax or deprecated symbols` inspection?

Comment: Thank you, this works partially for me, it finds usage of deprecated method calls where the method is in kotlin. But for method call to a java lib f.e. like `StringUtils.isEmpty(...)` with is located in a spring lib it will not be found. (other way around, searching for deprecated java API usage also don't find the issue in kotlin code (which makes sense, just wanted to note it)

Comment: Please, file an issue - https://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: that's indeed a good idea. and here we go: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311206/